# How to get .gcda files when the process is killed?

Tags: c++, g++, signals, compiler-optimization

I have a binary build with `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage`. The binary is run by a process monitor which spawns the process as a child process. Then, when I want the process to exit, I have to go through the process monitor. It sends a `SIGKILL` to the process. I found out that `.gcda` files do not generate in this case. What can I do?

EDIT: Actually the process monitor first tries to make the process exit. However, the ProcessMonitor library (used in each process) calls `_exit` instead of `exit` when the user issues a command to stop the process. This is the cause of all trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGKILL` is a "hard" kill signal, that cannot be caught by the application. Therefore, the app has no chance to write out the `.gcda` file.

I see two options:

1. Catch signals other than `SIGKILL`: any sensible process monitor should send a `SIGTERM` first. `init` and the batch managers I've encountered do this. `SIGKILL` is a last resort, so it should be sent only after `SIGTERM` followed by a grace period.
2. Workaround: run the program via an intermediate program that gets the `SIGKILL`; have the actual program check periodically (or in a separate thread) if its parent still lives, and if not, have it exit gracefully.

Comment: There are good reasons to use SIGKILL in many cases. One: reliable software should handle it and always using it guarantees it is tested for the worst case. Two: KILL shuts down without spending useless time cleaning memory allocations, closing files, etc.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: I edited my post, because you're partly right. However, (1) is not true for the simple reason that software *cannot* handle SIGKILL, by the design of Unix signals. (2) is not true because graceful cleanup is not useless.

Comment: By "handle it" I meant that software should be written to handle a dirty shutdown. It's a design philosophy. See here http://www.usenix.org/events/hotos03/tech/full_papers/candea/candea_html/ (2) if the software is "crash only" then it's a waste of time to clean anything up.

Comment: @Zan: Your reference makes interesting points regarding how transaction processing databases might behave, but the question at stake is how to profile in the face of a potential kill signal.

Comment: I did provide an answer to that. Not sure if it's working for nakiya or not. It relies on GCC library internals.

Answer (score 4):

This might work:
http://nixcraft.com/coding-general/12544-gcov-g.html

In summary: call __gcov_flush() in the program, possibly in a signal handler or periodically during execution.

If C++ code remember to make a extern "C" declaration of the function.

Also remember to use some kind of preprocessor ifdef so that the program does not call it when not built with profiling.

Comment: Is there a standard preprocessor symbol that's defined when compiling with `-ftest-coverage`?  Or do I need to manually specify something like `-DUSING_GCOV`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what was at the link, it has since broken. Here is a link to the internet archive version of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20130515182522/http://nixcraft.com/coding-general/12544-gcov-g.html

Comment: @jchl Apparently not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566151/test-if-coverage-enabled-in-g (the short answer appears to be no, see link for long answer, which is still no)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik compilers (IntelC too) only store profiling stats in exit handler.
So what about somehow telling the process to quit, instead of killing it?
Like adding a SIGKILL handler maybe, with exit() in it?

Comment: Can I catch `SIGKILL`? I thought you can't catch it. Only `SIGTERM`.